# Something similar to Cocoa Pods and Bundler for Android (for dependencies)?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

is there anything similar to bundler (ruby) and cocoa pods (ios) for managing dependencies in Android?

Comment: What problems are you facing with library dependencies in Android so far?  I haven't had any so I'm curious as to why you need a plugin/tool for it

Comment: well @JesseChen if you don't see the advantage of bundler or cocoapods I guess is because you haven't used them... take a look [here](http://gembundler.com/) or [here](http://cocoapods.org/) to understand the advantages of having an automated dependency management system

Comment: @JesseChen once you used one, you cannot do without one. ;)

Answer (score 16):

Gradle + Maven Central seems to be the Android equivalent.

Comment: how to search libs ? 
I have tried to add lib (searched from maven repo)but I am not sure the lib name and version , and I compiled with failures

Comment: @aelam This is a pretty neat site that I use sometimes - http://gradleplease.appspot.com/

Comment: awesome, thanks ！！
if gradle has office solution like dependency searching and contributing,just as cocoapods, it would be very convenient!!

Answer (score 11):

The [maven-android plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) provides similar dependency management. If all of the dependencies are in Maven Central, a typically a simple `mvn clean install` will build your Android project.