# Android equivalent to CocoaPods Pods-Acknowledgements.plist?

Tags: android

CocoaPods automatically generates a nice list of acknowledgements for all the projects I've used, so that I can include that info in my applications UI.

Is there something similar for the whole Android / Gradle situation?

More generally, how can I automate collecting and showing the appropriate acknowledgement / licensing info for the components I've used in my Android project?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771375/something-similar-to-cocoa-pods-and-bundler-for-android-for-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no all in one drop-in equivalent of CocoaPods acknowledgments for the Android ecosystem so far, probably because there is no equivalent of the iOS settings bundle on Android.

Option may be :

- **Generation** part : Use a gradle plugin to create reports about your dependencies licence : https://github.com/jk1/Gradle-License-Report or https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin (downloadLicenses task)
- **Show to the user** part : You'll have to do it manually, get the parts that you want from the reports and put it for example in your GooglePlay description, or store it wherever you want (local or remote) and show it to the user at first launch after install (https://github.com/prashantsolanki3/Shoot)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Maven Plug In](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/). you can use it with your gradle and equivalent to `cocoapods`

**Update ::**

use [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) to add your dependency in it .

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how Maven would help automate this?  I can't find anything at the link you provided.

Comment: sorry If I am not specific . see my updated answer and use sonatype = http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html to add your dependency or project to maven central